# datepicker not working after making ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

//here the code for calling date picker

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
       $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Select...'
    });

});
</script>
<input class="datepicker" disabled="disabled" />
```

//Here Im making an ajax call

```
function reFresh(name){
            $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"Phase",
            data:{projectName:name},
            async: false,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(data) {
               $("#Left_Panel").html(data);

            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Error ! In fetching data.");
            }
        })

}
```

// After coming to the first page again using ajax , now datepicker not working .

Comment: missing parameter for error function error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}

Comment: @JYoThI what does it have to do with the question? Btw @OP, what is `#Left_Panel` where you set data from ajax?

Comment: it will give the actual error  instead of     "Error ! In fetching data."  @debute

Comment: @JYoThI that's right, but problem is that datapicker is not working after fetching data, not with the ajax itself.

Comment: @debute got the problem. help me to fix this

Comment: i never said that it was the reason for datepicker not working . i just notified the user  .*missing parameter for error function error*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the element holding the datepicker is contained in the `#Left_Panel` element, then the issue is because that element is destroyed and re-created, hence the original event handler is lost. To fix this, you need to reinstantiate the library on the element after the AJAX completes.

Also note that using `aysnc: false` is very bad practice - in fact the browser will be giving you a warning in the console telling you not to do it.

Try this:

```
function reFresh(name){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Phase",
    data: { projectName: name },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#Left_Panel").html(data).find('.datepicker').datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Select...'
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error ! In fetching data.");
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: In that case we need more information. What is the HTML being loaded? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @JAGATDAS is your `.datepicker` within `#Left_Panel`? Since we can't tell from the question.

Comment: @debute yes datepicker is in #Left_Panel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go this way.

First, make function where you init the datepicker:

```
function refreshDatepicker() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        constrainInput: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Select...'
    });
}
```

Second, call this function whenever you need it to - after DOM load, after ajax call, etc. This way it will be easier to maintain:

```
$(function() {
    refreshDatepicker();
});
```

Third, after successfully fetching data from ajax call this function again, so it will re-init all datepickers in the DOM.

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#Left_Panel").html(data);
    refreshDatepicker();
}
```

If this won't work, then problem is in fetched data. Check the data from ajax if it comes well, then check if it contains input with class `datepicker`, etc. Otherwise I don't see why this won't work. If you get any error in the console let me know.

Comment: Nope No improvement .